# download Ribbon Control for WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, download, ribbon

From where should i download ribbon control ?

Comment: you can make use of the Scenic Ribbon too,which is an integrated ribbon framework for windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go to this url and download design guidelines and control binaries... see below at page

http://www.msassetsupport.com/officeUI/license/

Answer (score 2):

check this out
[CodePlex Resources for WPF Ribbon](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf/Wiki/View.aspx?title=WPF%20Ribbon%20Preview)

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting: "You are not authorized to view this page"

strange...

See "[Where to find the WPF Office Ribbon control?](http://teusje.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/wpf-office-ribbon-control/)"